# DLL Stops being found in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, dll

I'm experiencing a strange problem where a DLL spontaneously stops being found by an Azure application after days of working.

Details as follows (sorry for the length I don't want to miss anything):

We have an ASP.NET MVC Azure application that among things creates mp3s using the lame library. The DLL for this library is located in the root of the project and is set to "Content" and "Copy Always".

The project, including the DLL deploys correctly and works when deployed.

After several weeks of working correctly the mp3 encoder stopped working giving an error

> Unable to load DLL 'libmp3lame.64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

This was on a Saturday - nothing had been changed on the server.

I was away from the computer and instructed a coworker to RDP into the Azure machine and replace the libmp3lame.64.dll thinking it had some how become corrupt and sure enough it started working.

Several days later this happened again. This time I copied down the DLL from Azure and compared the MD5 to the local copy I have - it matched.

I redeployed and now everything is working fine again.

What could possible cause this, and how can it be avoided??

Thank you.

UPDATE: Yes an IIS restart also does resolve the issue.

Comment: If you recycle the application pool, does it start working again?

Comment: @John Koerner I plan to try next time if it happens again. There was a bit of a rush to get it back online so I did what I knew would work.

Comment: How are you deploying the project?

Comment: @adaam Build>Publish to Windows Azure

Comment: I have a feeling that this might be the answer to your problems.. https://github.com/Corey-M/NAudio.Lame/wiki/Using-NAudio.Lame-with-MVC

Comment: @adaam That certainly sounds plausible and I will try that solution. Thank you! Just wondering why it works for a while then stops...

Comment: Update: an IIS restart does correct the problem